# resizing a div without changing the position of sides

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a div with handles that can be used to resize it. Those work well when the rotation of the div is 0 deg. But when angle of rotation changes and I try to resize the div from one side, the position of other sides changes. I want to keep the position fixed of rest of sides when I try to resize it at from one handle. Here is my code: Help me what type of changes should I do in it.

```js
 const resizableDiv = document.querySelector('#resizable-div');
        const handles = document.querySelectorAll('.handle');

        let isResizing = false;
        let currentHandle = null;
        let originalWidth = 0;
        let originalHeight = 0;
        let originalX = 0;
        let originalY = 0;
        let currentX = 0;
        let currentY = 0;

        handles.forEach(handle => {
            handle.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
                isResizing = true;
                currentHandle = handle;
                originalWidth = resizableDiv.offsetWidth;
                originalHeight = resizableDiv.offsetHeight;
                originalX = resizableDiv.offsetLeft;
                originalY = resizableDiv.offsetTop;
                currentX = e.pageX;
                currentY = e.pageY;
            });
        });

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
            isResizing = false;
        });

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
            if (!isResizing) return;
            let deltaX = e.pageX - currentX;
            let deltaY = e.pageY - currentY;
            if (currentHandle.classList.contains('handle-n')) {
                resizableDiv.style.height = originalHeight - deltaY + 'px';
                resizableDiv.style.top = originalY + deltaY + 'px';
            } else if (currentHandle.classList.contains('handle-e')) {
                resizableDiv.style.width = originalWidth + deltaX + 'px';
            } else if (currentHandle.classList.contains('handle-s')) {
                resizableDiv.style.height = originalHeight + deltaY + 'px';
            } else if (currentHandle.classList.contains('handle-w')) {
                resizableDiv.style.width = originalWidth - deltaX + 'px';
                resizableDiv.style.left = originalX + deltaX + 'px';
            }
        });

        // rotation


        const rotateHandle = document.querySelector('.rotate-handle');
        let isDragging = false;
        let currentDeg = 0;
        let startX = 0;
        let startY = 0;

        rotateHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
            isDragging = true;
            startX = e.clientX;
            startY = e.clientY;
        });

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
            isDragging = false;
        });

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
            if (!isDragging) return;
            const deltaX = e.clientX - startX;
            const deltaY = e.clientY - startY;
            currentDeg = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * (180 / Math.PI);
            resizableDiv.style.transform = `rotate(${currentDeg}deg)`;
        });
```

```css
#resizable-div {
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            left: 50px;
            top: 50px;
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
        
        .handle {
            position: absolute;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        
        .handle-n {
            top: -5px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            cursor: n-resize;
        }
        
        .handle-e {
            right: -5px;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            cursor: e-resize;
        }
        
        .handle-s {
            bottom: -5px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            cursor: s-resize;
        }
        
        .handle-w {
            left: -5px;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            cursor: w-resize;
        }
        
        .rotate-handle {
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<div id="resizable-div">
        <div class="handle handle-n"></div>
        <div class="handle handle-e"></div>
        <div class="handle handle-s"></div>
        <div class="handle handle-w"></div>
        <div class="handle rotate-handle"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Setting [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) might help ..?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
I removed the `left` and `top event` from `JS`, anded a `container` to the `resizable-div` element and added `flex` to it.

```js
 const resizableDiv = document.querySelector('#resizable-div');
        const handles = document.querySelectorAll('.handle');

        let isResizing = false;
        let currentHandle = null;
        let originalWidth = 0;
        let originalHeight = 0;
        let originalX = 0;
        let originalY = 0;
        let currentX = 0;
        let currentY = 0;

        handles.forEach(handle => {
            handle.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
                isResizing = true;
                currentHandle = handle;
                originalWidth = resizableDiv.offsetWidth;
                originalHeight = resizableDiv.offsetHeight;
                originalX = resizableDiv.offsetLeft;
                originalY = resizableDiv.offsetTop;
                currentX = e.pageX;
                currentY = e.pageY;
            });
        });

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
            isResizing = false;
        });

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
            if (!isResizing) return;
            let deltaX = e.pageX - currentX;
            let deltaY = e.pageY - currentY;
            if (currentHandle.classList.contains('handle-n')) {
                resizableDiv.style.height = originalHeight - deltaY + 'px';
            } else if (currentHandle.classList.contains('handle-e')) {
                resizableDiv.style.width = originalWidth + deltaX + 'px';
            } else if (currentHandle.classList.contains('handle-s')) {
                resizableDiv.style.height = originalHeight + deltaY + 'px';
            } else if (currentHandle.classList.contains('handle-w')) {
                resizableDiv.style.width = originalWidth - deltaX + 'px';
            }
        });

        // rotation


        const rotateHandle = document.querySelector('.rotate-handle');
        let isDragging = false;
        let currentDeg = 0;
        let startX = 0;
        let startY = 0;

        rotateHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
            isDragging = true;
            startX = e.clientX;
            startY = e.clientY;
        });

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
            isDragging = false;
        });

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
            if (!isDragging) return;
            const deltaX = e.clientX - startX;
            const deltaY = e.clientY - startY;
            currentDeg = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * (180 / Math.PI);
            resizableDiv.style.transform = `rotate(${currentDeg}deg)`;
        });
```

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  min-height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

#resizable-div {
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
  
            background-color: #ddd;
  transform-orgin:top left;
        }
        
        .handle {
            position: absolute;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        
        .handle-n {
            top: -5px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            cursor: n-resize;
        }
        
        .handle-e {
            right: -5px;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            cursor: e-resize;
        }
        
        .handle-s {
            bottom: -5px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            cursor: s-resize;
        }
        
        .handle-w {
            left: -5px;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            cursor: w-resize;
        }
        
        .rotate-handle {
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="resizable-div">
          <div class="handle handle-n"></div>
          <div class="handle handle-e"></div>
          <div class="handle handle-s"></div>
          <div class="handle handle-w"></div>
          <div class="handle rotate-handle"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It works but now it is being scaled on both sides. I'm still struggling with handling the resize problem